# Android Bluetooth program crashing

Tags: android, crash, bluetooth

I am using code from another website [here](http://project-greengiant.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Blog/Android%20Arduino%20Bluetooth/Android/AndroidArduinoBluetooth/src/Android/Arduino/Bluetooth/BluetoothTest.java).

My question is... When I use any of the buttons on my Android device, the application crashes and says, "Unfortunately, Bluetooth has stopped." When I compile there are no errors. Any information on how to diagnose this problem would be greatly appreciated. Bluetooth applications are much harder to diagnose because you cannot simulate on the emulator!

Thanks for any help!

```
package Android.Arduino.Bluetooth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothTest extends Activity
{
    TextView myLabel;
    EditText myTextbox;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    InputStream mmInputStream;
    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
        Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);

        //Open Button
        openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    findBT();
                    openBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

        //Send Button
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    sendData();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });

        //Close button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try 
                {
                    closeBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
            }
        });
    }

    void findBT()
    {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
        }

        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            {
                if(device.getName().equals("MattsBlueTooth")) 
                {
                    mmDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
    }

    void openBT() throws IOException
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();

        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
    }

    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
               {
                    try 
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                            {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if(b == delimiter)
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            myLabel.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
               }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }

    void sendData() throws IOException
    {
        String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
        msg += "\n";
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
    }

    void closeBT() throws IOException
    {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just catching the Exceptions, what about logging them -> should give you feedback why the app crashed. Any logs would be useful..

Comment: Any explanation how to do this would be greatly appreciated! (or link)

Comment: Logs can be viewed in your IDE in the logcat-View/Tab. To Log use: Log.w("YourAppName", e.getMessage(), e);