# Bluetooth signal dead nodification

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an application with a server based Database project. In this, I'm getting trouble with the Wi-fi and Bluetooth devices.

If i move out of the range with my tablet means, my process were getting hanged with that moment itself, for resolving this problem help me..

I am trying to develop a program for the Bluetooth strength calculator or notification manager for that, anybody help me..

Thank you,..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562875/android-bluetooth-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out with the Bluetooth adapter and for the Connections. Use the following link for the tutorial and try with it..

[Bluetooth adapter..](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-quick-look-bluetoothadapter/)

And Look out this Example and try like it as,..

[First Example Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736967/displaying-a-notification-when-bluetooth-is-disconnected-android)

[Second Example Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171817/android-bluetooth-program-crashing)

These examples will help you!..

Comment: Will these things work? Because they are questions asked by someones